# Why isn't this combobox displaying items?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I'm writing an import utility, I'd like for users to be able to upload from a CSV and then direct the columns where they'd like them to go.

So in order to do this, I'm making the header of each column a ComboBox populated with all of the possible columns.

xaml

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="ImportTable" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding displayTable}"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="True" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                  MaxWidth="1300"
                  MaxHeight="600"
                  />
```

xaml.cs

```
    private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {

        var cb = new ComboBox();
        foreach (DataColumn test in (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(test);

        cb.ItemsSource = (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns;
        e.Column.Header = cb;
    }
```

This correctly prints out all of the columns, but nothing is actually displayed inside of the combo box's

[Empty Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv8zn.png)

---

The combobox now displays properly in the dropdown. but i can't get it's selectedValue to set. The following code prints out that the selectedvalue is correct, but it's still populating initially as blank/unselected

```
        var cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.DisplayMemberPath = "ColumnName";
        cb.SelectedValue = e.PropertyName.ToString();
        cb.ItemsSource = (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns;
        Console.Out.WriteLine(cb.SelectedValue);
        e.Column.Header = cb;
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `DisplayMemberPath` property for your combobox? To me it looks like you may have items, those items are just displayed as blanks.

Comment: how would you go about setting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the `DisplayMemberPath` of your combobox.

```
    private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {

        var cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.DisplayMemberPath = "SomePropertyFromYourCollection";
        foreach (DataColumn test in (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns)
            Console.Out.WriteLine(test);

        cb.ItemsSource = (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns;
        e.Column.Header = cb;
    }
```

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: this was correct! thank you I'd like to set the selectedValue to e.PropertyName. but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `DisplayMemberPath` and the `SelectedValuePath` of the combo box I think.

These will be column names from your data file.

It should look something like this:

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = new ComboBox();
    foreach (DataColumn test in (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(test);

    cb.ItemsSource = (DataContext as EnterValueDialogViewModel).displayTable.Columns;
    cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Column1";
    cb.SelectedValuePath = "Column2";
    e.Column.Header = cb;
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: So I've got DisplayMemberPath pointing to "ColumnName" and that works. I'd like to selectedValue to be based on e.PropertyName. which should be that columns default header. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What if you say `e.PropertyName.ToString()`

Comment: just added to the question. I'm doing this.